# Check notification type using UNNotificationSettings in iOS 10

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios10, usernotifications

How can I use `UNNotificationSettings` to get the notification type in iOS 10?

On previous iOS, I would use this:

```
UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];

Bool active = notificationSettings.types == UIUserNotificationTypeNone ? NO: YES;
```

Comment: So you are asking how to use the `UNNotificationSettings` class?

Comment: Yes you right...I am not able to find the way to use enums.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check whether user notifications are enabled after UILocalNotification deprecation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46664177/check-whether-user-notifications-are-enabled-after-uilocalnotification-deprecati)

Answer (score 10):

I hope you are asking about this

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler{ (mySettings) in  mySettings.alertStyle == .None }
```

Swift 4

`UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings{ (mySettings) in  mySettings.alertStyle == .none }`

For Objective-C

```
[[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler:^(UNNotificationSettings * _Nonnull settings) {
    settings.alertStyle == UNAlertStyleNone
}]
```

Comment: How to do it in objective-c?

Comment: @MehulChuahan Updated answer with Objective-C code.