# Check whether user notifications are enabled after UILocalNotification deprecation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, usernotifications

In my app, I want to be able to check if the user has notifications enabled or not. In iOS 10, I did this using a check in the delegate.

This check is now deprecated and I want to update it, but I can't figure out what to use in iOS 11.

The deprecation warning is as follows:

> currentUserNotificationSettings' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: Use
>   UserNotifications Framework's -[UNUserNotificationCenter
>   getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler:] and
>   -[UNUserNotificationCenter getNotificationCategoriesWithCompletionHandler:]

I've tried to update the code with the help of this warning but I can't figure it out.

If anyone can suggest anyway to get a check like this working it would help a lot. The code I have been using for iOS 10 is below, thanks.

```
let notificationType = UIApplication.shared.currentUserNotificationSettings!.types
if notificationType == [] {
    print("Notifications are NOT enabled")
} else {
    print("Notifications are enabled")
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Step 1 : `import UserNotifications`

Step 2 :

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
  if settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized {
    // Notifications are allowed
  }
  else {
    // Either denied or notDetermined
  }
}
```

Inspect the settings object for more informations.

Comment: how do you handle this in pre iOS 10?

Comment: You would have to get a `UIUserNotificationSettings` object from **UIApplication.shared** via the `currentUserNotificationSettings` method.

Comment: How do you convert this into a func which throws Bool()?

Answer (score 9):

**First step:**

You have to add header file as

```
import UserNotifications
```

I have used *checkpushNotification* method to check whether user enable notification or not. Uses called this method from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of AppDelegate class. Hope It will help you, If any problem then comment below.

**Last step:**

```
func checkPushNotification(){
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings(){ (setttings) in
                
                switch setttings.authorizationStatus{
                case .authorized:
                    
                    print("enabled notification setting")
                    
                case .denied:
                    
                    print("setting has been disabled")
                    
                case .notDetermined:
                    print("something vital went wrong here")
                }
            }
        } else {

            let isNotificationEnabled = UIApplication.shared.currentUserNotificationSettings?.types.contains(UIUserNotificationType.alert)
            if isNotificationEnabled{
                
                print("enabled notification setting")
            }else{
                
                print("setting has been disabled")
            }
        }
    }
```

And if you want certain boolean output for is enabled or disabled then you should  implement completion handler to solve it.

```
func checkPushNotification(checkNotificationStatus isEnable : ((Bool)->())? = nil){
        
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings(){ (setttings) in
                
                switch setttings.authorizationStatus{
                case .authorized:
                    
                    print("enabled notification setting")
                    isEnable?(true)
                case .denied:
                    
                    print("setting has been disabled")
                    isEnable?(false)
                case .notDetermined:
                    
                    print("something vital went wrong here")
                    isEnable?(false)
                }
            }
        } else {
            
            let isNotificationEnabled = UIApplication.shared.currentUserNotificationSettings?.types.contains(UIUserNotificationType.alert)
            if isNotificationEnabled == true{
                
                print("enabled notification setting")
                isEnable?(true)

            }else{
                
                print("setting has been disabled")
                isEnable?(false)
            }
        }
    }
```

and Call this simple as

```
  self.checkPushNotification {  (isEnable) in
    print(isEnable)
    // you know notification status.
}
```

Comment: and for earlier versions?

Comment: @Josh i have updated for earlier version above. If it did not work please comment below.

Comment: @ Amrit Tiwari does that imply that if isNotificationEnabled = false, it has been denied? does it work the same way as in the earlier switch case in your example?

Comment: isNotificationEnabled = false, this is for both case user denied and not determined.

Comment: Hi Amrit, could you show me how to convert your function to throw Bool() as result? like -> Bool()?

Comment: @AmritTiwari are u able to share how did u throw a bool() here?

Comment: @Desmond i have updated answer please look and hope this will solved your problem. if any confusion feel free to ask.

Comment: @AmritTiwari thanks for the edits! do you know how I could getNotificationSettings callback to a synchronous method and return a Bool?

Comment: @Desmond why you want synchronous method?

Answer (score -1):

I think you can just call `UIApplication.shared.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications`